# Class Enum java

Tags: java, enums

I have this enum class.

When I call the controller it gives me null

```
public enum Gender {

    MALE("Male", "M"),
    FEMALE("Female", "F"),
    OTHER("OTHER", "O");

    private String description;
    private String value;


    private Gender(String description, String value) {
        description = description;
        value = value;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return description;
    }
}


List<Gender> listGender = Arrays.asList(Gender.values());
for (Gender o : Gender.values()) {
   System.out.println(o.toString());
}
```

Answer
null

Thanks for what you can help me

Translate with google translate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake inside the enum constructor. Use the keyword `this` to assign value to object's attributes (an enum is an object).

```
private Gender(String description, String value) {
    this.description = description;
    this.value = value;
}
```

Comment: I was wrong to copy it and do not modify the constructor

Comment: You need to initialize attributes in the constructor Gender, using `this` keyword before the attribute's names. Without that the attribute stay null because the variables description and value referred to method's parameters and not to the class attributes.

Comment: `this` is all it needs